# Question about coin tosses and conditional probability

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution, random-variable, conditional-probability

**Case 1: Fair coin**

Consider a coin that is known ahead of time to have probability P=0.5 for heads or tails for a coin toss.
Tom claims he can predict whether a toss will come up heads or not more often than would happen by chance.
The null hypothesis is that his predictions will be consistent with random results.

Tom performs N coin flip trials, and gets K hits, where a hit is defined as his predicting heads when heads come up, and tails when tails comes up.

Tom computes the one-tailed binomial p-value for P=0.5, and finds that the p-value is less than .05, indicating that the null hypothesis does not hold, his claim may be true, something statistically significant might be happening outside random chance.

**Case 2: Unfair coin**

Now consider an unfair coin, with Ph=0.6 for heads, Pt= 0.4 for tails.
Dave does not know ahead of time about the coin being unfair.
He is just performing a binary prediction, is the coin toss going to be heads or not.
He does N trials with K hits.

**Question:**

Does he still use P=0.5 as the probability when computing the p-value? The rationale being the prediction is binary, so for a given coin toss being Heads is Yes or No, the random chance of either is still 0.5.

Or is it now necessary to use Ph=0.6 and Pt=0.4 to compute the p-value separately for Heads predictions and Tails predictions?

Is this an example of conditional probability, and if so, what are the calculations necessary to arrive at the expected probabilities P to use to compute the p-values?